# Indenting code in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, geshi

Is it possible to indent a block of code in MediaWiki using [SyntaxHighlight GeSHi](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi)?

For example, I would like the code container below to be aligned with the third-level list

```
* This is plain text of a first-level list to be rendered by MediaWiki
** This is plain text of a a second-level list to be rendered by MediaWiki
*** This is plain text of a third-level list to be rendered by MediaWiki

<source lang="Cpp">
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    my_function(4, 1, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
</source>
```

I have tried wrapping the GeSHi code container with [colons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_(punctuation)) (using  MediaWiki's standard [indentation syntax](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Formatting)), but that prevents SyntaxHighlight GeSHi from parsing the code correctly.

Just to clarify, I would like to avoid wrapping my code with `<code></code>` as I need proper syntax highlighting.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could always wrap it with normal HTML div tags as well:

```
<div style="margin-left: 2em;">
  <source ...>
    ...
  </source>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer, thanks!  This works reasonably well, but it does not allow you to continue the list below the code block -- a `***` will give you a triple-bullet, and a `::*` isn't quite the same (but the best solution I know of).

Comment: Is it really not possible to indent a dozen of code lines? Can't accept it -- there must be some way to do this. I 've tried too many things (reading [Meta, WikiMedia, Help:List](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:List)) and still did not find it. Any expert?

Comment: Dan: as of June 2013 there is no way to continue the numbering other than with HTML commands. See http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:List#Specifying_a_starting_value. So the only solution to your problem is to us <ol> and friends.

Answer (score 4):

You can put the source inside a table, and then indent the table:

```
:::{|
|
<source ...>
...
</source>
|}
```

Comment: Would have been wonderful, if instead of indentation (:::), it could also be done by normal bulleted list (#*). In other words, it would be good to have the ability to put a table as a bulleted item.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a way to misuse the `<ul>...</ul>` HTML element? A possible workaround is given (by Jeremy Koppel) at [Meta, WikiMedia, Help:Editing FAQ](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help%3aEditing_FAQ) among the answers to the question [Can I put preformatted text inside a numbered list?](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help%3aEditing_FAQ#Q%3a_Can_I_put_preformatted_text_inside_a_numbered_list.3F):

> ```
> <ul>
>       <li>one</li>
>       <li>two<pre>
>
> Here are a couple lines...
> ...of preformatted text
>
>       </pre></li>
>       <li>and the numbering</li>
>       <li>starts over</li>
>    </ul>
> ```

I successfuly used this, in a WikiMedia based wiki, to highlight bash code under a bulleted text line, as follows:

```
 <ul>
<source lang="bash">sudo apt-get install \
build-essential \
...
libglu1-mesa-dev libxmu-dev</source>
   </ul>
```

Did not succeed to make it work for deeper levels though!